# Why this error "Could not find or load main class" appears when I execute the main class in a spring boot project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

hello guys when I executed the main class (as application) of a spring boot project in eclipse this error appears:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
> com.aymen.StockManagement.ApiStockManagementApplication Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.aymen.StockManagement.ApiStockManagementApplication

I hope that anyone can help me resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that you're missing this bit in your pom.xml?

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```